# magento replce attribute value in template file

Tags: magento, replace, attributes

On our Magento website we make use of an attribute with three values consisting of the numbers 1, 2 and 3. In the category list view we use these attribute values as indication for the delivery times of the products. Whe show a certain image depending the value of the attribute through

`if($_product->getResource()->getAttribute('delivery')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)=="3"){
    print ("<img src=http://www.example.com/media/wysiwyg/3.gif> Delivery can take over 20 days");}`

Now we want to do the same thing with this attribute on the product page in the extra info tab. I have experimented with attributes.phtml but can't get this to work.

Is there anyone who knows how we can get the values of this specific attribute replaced by an image and a line of text in the attributes.phtml file?

Regards,
Erik

Answer (score 1):

In order for your attribute to be available within the attributes.phtml collection, you need to set it to "Visible on Product View Page on Front-end" = Yes.

From admin, go to;

```
Catalog > Attribute > Manage Attributes
```

(from the top menu).

Find your attribute and open it, then set "Visible on Product View Page on Front-end" to 'Yes' and save.

Comment: I am aware of that but the fact is that we need to replace the values from that specific attribute on the product page. The attribute has three values consisting of the numbers 1, 2 and 3. We want to use this attribute and we know that the attribute should be set to visible on the frontend. We just want to replace the values with an image on the productpage.

Comment: so just compare the attribute value with your integer and replace with your required text/image/html ?

Comment: PixieMedia, indeed, that is what we want to achieve.